# Why does my SKSpriteNode work but only temporarily

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm learning SpriteKit with a tutorial about a simple card game. I have a scene on which I put two cards, the nodes. I should be able to click on either one of the cards, pick it up, move it around, and drop it. Strangely, I can do this, but usually just once. If I try to do it again it sometimes works, but many times I get the spinning beachball and have to bounce the simulator to get it working again. It's simple code but I just can't figure out why it's doing this.

```
enum CardName: Int {
    case CreatureWolf = 0,
    CreatureBear
}

class Card : SKSpriteNode {
let frontTexture: SKTexture
let backTexture: SKTexture
var largeTexture: SKTexture?
let largeTextureFilename: String

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

init(cardNamed: CardName) {

    // initialize properties
    backTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "card_back.png")

    switch cardNamed {
    case .CreatureWolf:
        frontTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "card_creature_wolf.png")
        largeTextureFilename = "card_creature_wolf_large.png"

    case .CreatureBear:
        frontTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "card_creature_bear.png")
        largeTextureFilename = "Card_creature_bear_large.png"

    default:
        frontTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "card_back.png")
        largeTextureFilename = "card_back_large.png"
    }

    // call designated initializer on super
    super.init(texture: frontTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: frontTexture.size())


    // set properties defined in super
    userInteractionEnabled = true
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for _ in touches {
        zPosition = 15
        let liftUp = SKAction.scaleTo(1.2, duration: 0.2)
        runAction(liftUp, withKey: "pickup")
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(scene!)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
        touchedNode.position = location
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for _ in touches {
        zPosition = 0
        let dropDown = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.2)
        runAction(dropDown, withKey: "drop")
    }
  }
}
```

Here the code that puts the cards on the scene:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  PlanningPoker

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      let wolf = Card(cardNamed: .CreatureWolf)
      wolf.position = CGPointMake(400,600)
      addChild(wolf)

      let bear = Card(cardNamed: .CreatureBear)
      bear.position = CGPointMake(600, 600)
      addChild(bear)
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening or how I can debug it? I've added print statements to the beginning and end of each 'touches*' function to make sure it's getting through them as expected (and it is), Xcode isn't giving me any warnings or errors, I've double-checked the code against the tutorial 27 times to make sure it matches (it does, with the exception of a few things I had to change to bring it up to Swift 2.1) and it should be working.

Thanks

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted. I suggest you post the code that creates and adds the cards to the scene.

Comment: I've added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is this is incorrect.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(scene!)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
        touchedNode.position = location
    }
}
```

you are getting the correct location but you may not get the node you want. You are actually trying to move the node that is calling this method. There is no need to try to get a different node.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(scene!)
        position = location
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have fixed it. The tutorial started with the touches functions on the scene and later had me move them to Card.swift. It said remove 'let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)' from the Began and Ended method when they're in the Card class but didn't say to do it in the Moved method, but it makes perfect sense.